# Intercept or filter out oplog transactions from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

There is a MongoDB which has interesting data I want to examine.  Unfortunately, due to size concerns, once every 48 hours, the database is purged of "old" records.

I created a replica set with a secondary database system that has priority 0 and vote 0 so as not to interfere with the main database performance.  This works great as I can query the secondary and get my data.  However, there are many occasions that my system cannot process all the records in time and will lose some old records if I did not get to them within 48 hours.

Is there a way where I can cache the oplog on another system which I can then process at my leisure, possibly filtering out the deletes until I am ready?

I considered the slavedelay parameters, but that will affect all transactions.  I also looked into Tungsten Replicate as a solution so I can essentially cache the the oplogs, however, they do not support MongoDB as a source of the data.

Is the oplog stored in plain text on the secondary such that I can read it and extract what I want from it.

Any pointers to this would be helpful, unfortunately I could not find much documentation on Oplog in the MongoDB website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB oplog is stored as a capped collection called 'oplog.rs' in your local DB:

```
use local
db.oplog.rs.find()
```

If you want to store more old data in oplog for later use, you can try to increase the size of that collection. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/change-oplog-size/

Alternatively, you can recreate oplog.rs as an uncapped collection (though this is not recommended since you will have to maually clean up oplog). Follow the same steps to increase the size above, but when recreating the oplog, use this command

```
db.runCommand( { create: "oplog.rs", capped: false})
```

Another solution is to create a cron job with the following command dump oplog into the folder YYYYMMDD:

```
mongodump --db local --collection oplog.rs -o $(date +%Y%m%d)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you would do that manually. The "canonical" way to do it is to either identify the lifetime or expiration date of a record. If it is a lifetime, you'd do sth like

```
db.collection.insert({'foo':'bar' [...], created: ISODate("2014-10-06T09:00:05Z")})
```

and

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({'created':1},{expireAfterSeconds:172800})
```

By doing so, a thread called TTLMonitor will awake every minute and remove all documents which have a created field which is older than two days.

If you have a fixed expiration date for each document, you'd basically do the same:

```
db.collection.insert({'foo':'bar' [...], expirationDate: ISODate("2100-01-01T00:00:00Z"})
```

and

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({expirationDate:1},{expireAfterSeconds:0})
```

This will purge the documents in the first run of TTLMonitor after the `expirationDate`.

You could adjust `expireAfterSeconds` to a value which safely allows you to process the records before they are purged, keeping the overall size at acceptable needs and making sure that even when your application goes down during the purging work, the records are removed. (Not to mention that you don't need to maintain the purging logic yourself).

That being said and in the hope it might be useful to you, I think your problem is a conceptual one.

You have a scaling problem. You system is unable to deal with peaks, hence it occasionally is unable to process all data in time. Instead of fiddling with the internals of MongoDB (which might be quite dangerous, as @chianh correctly pointed out), you should rather scale accordingly by identifying your bottleneck and scale it according to your peaks.

Comment: Thank Markus, the information you present is interesting.  In my case I do not own the data and I need to tread lightly.  I will suggest that they utilize the expiration approach as an alternative.  As for my system, I can ingest their data very quickly, but it is under development and may have many outages, as a result I will run behind and don't want to miss any data in the meantime.